# How to get De-Duplicated OpenIE (Clause Extraction) Results?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, information-extraction

I've exhausted all the configuration options I'm aware of:

```
from openie import StanfordOpenIE
  
# https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html#api
# Default value of openie.affinity_probability_cap was 1/3.
properties = {
    "annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie",
    'openie.affinity_probability_cap': 2 / 3,
    "openie.triple.strict":"true",
    'openie.max_entailments_per_clause': 1,
    'splitter.disable': True
}

with StanfordOpenIE(properties=properties) as client:
    text = 'Barack Obama was born in Hawaii. Richard Manning wrote this sentence.'
    print('Text: %s.' % text)
    for triple in client.annotate(text): #, max_entailments_per_clause=True):
        print('|-', triple)
```

But the results still contain non-merged duplicating variations:

```
|- {'subject': 'Barack Obama', 'relation': 'was', 'object': 'born'}
|- {'subject': 'Barack Obama', 'relation': 'was born in', 'object': 'Hawaii'}
```

Whereas I'm only looking for the maximal clause extraction results:

```
|- {'subject': 'Barack Obama', 'relation': 'was born in', 'object': 'Hawaii'}
```

Can someone help me out on this please?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
from pycorenlp import *
import json
import nltk

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP("http://localhost:9000/")
text = 'Barack Obama was born in Hawaii. Richard Manning wrote this sentence.'

props = {"annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie",
                                  "outputFormat": "json",
                                  "openie.triple.strict": "true",
                                  "openie.max_entailments_per_clause": "1"}
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
for sent in sentences:
    print(sent)
    output = nlp.annotate(sent, properties=props)
    j_data = json.loads(output)
    openie = j_data['sentences'][0]['openie']
    for i in openie:
        for rel in i:
            relationSen = i['subject'], i['relation'], i['object']
    print(relationSen)
```

it produces the following output...

```
Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.
('Barack Obama', 'was born in', 'Hawaii')
Richard Manning wrote this sentence.
('Richard Manning', 'wrote', 'sentence')
```